# Product inheritance in case classes

Tags: scala, inheritance, case-class

I have some case classes that extend a common superclass and I'd like to access fields from the superclass using `productElement` method (I've tryed to declare base class as a case class but I get a frightening warning about the dangers of inheritance of case classes and yet doesn't work).

I can imagine some solution like this:

```
abstract class A(a: Int) extends Product {
  def productArity = 1
  def productElement(n: Int) = if (n == 0) a else throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException
}

case class B(b: Int) extends A(1) {
  def productArity = super.productArity + 1  
  def productElement(n: Int) = if (n < super.productArity) super.productElement(n) else ....
}
```

but it was getting so ugly that I can't even finish.

Does anybody know a better solution?

Comment: Can you make `A` an `abstract case class`?

Comment: Yes, I've done it and I get this: _Case-to-case inheritance has potentially dangerous bugs which are unlikely to be fixed.  You are strongly encouraged to instead use extractors to pattern match on non-leaf nodes._ Besides it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest I can get is to not implement anything in A

```
scala> abstract class A(val a: Int) extends Product
defined class A

scala> case class B(override val a: Int, b: String) extends A(a)
defined class B

scala> val anA: A = B(42, "banana")
anA: A = B(42,banana)

scala> anA.a
res37: Int = 42

scala> anA.productArity
res38: Int = 2

scala> anA.productElement(1)
res39: Any = banana

scala> anA.productElement(0)
res40: Any = 42
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea! It led me to this other solution:
`abstract class A(val a: Int) extends Product`
`case class B(b: String, override val a: Int = 42) extends A(a)`
the only drawback is that 'a' won't be in the same position for all subclasses.

Answer (score 4):

In Scala trunk a lot of this is done for you already: case classes now extend the appropriate ProductN trait. Only case class direct (ie. not inherited) members are included in the product however, so if you need to include members from a super type, they would have to be abstract in the super type and given a concrete implementation in the case class.

Here's a REPL session (Scala trunk, 2.10.0.r25951-b20111107020214),

```
scala> trait A { val a: Int }
defined trait A

scala> case class B(b: Int, a : Int = 1) extends A                                                                                                                                                     
defined class B                                                                                                                                                                                        

scala> val b = B(23)
b: B = B(23,1)                                                                                                                                                                                         

scala> b.productArity
res0: Int = 2                                                                                                                                                                                          

scala> b.productElement(0)
res1: Any = 23                                                                                                                                                                                         

scala> b.productElement(1)
res2: Any = 1                                                                                                                                                                                          

scala> b._1      // use Product method ... note result type
res6: Int = 23                                                                                                                                                                                         

scala> b._2      // use Product method ... note result type                                                                                                                                                                                            
res7: Int = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution looks nicer than the previous one (`abstract class`), but I still can't figure out a way to put inherited members at first positions. I'd like to avoid some clumsy code like `x.productElement( x.productArity - 1 )`

Comment: For some reason, this was dropped in 2.10. Do you know why?

Comment: @Blaisorblade I forget the details the devil was hiding in, but you can follow progress (or the lack thereof) [here](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-1799).